# Using a full-page watermark via \includegraphics?

Tags: watermark, draftwatermark

I used Sergio Callegari's `draftwatermark.sty` in the past, simply redefining `\sc@watermark` to include my full-page single-page pdf.  Alas, I think this is no longer working in the latest 2020 version of draftwatermark:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{draftwatermark}

\makeatletter
%% \renewcommand\sc@watermark{\includegraphics{backgroundimage.pdf}}%% used to work in older versions
  %% includes file, but is no longer the stamp background in the previewer.
\renewcommand\draftwatermark@printwm{\includegraphics{./backgroundimage.pdf}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

This is just some text. This is just some text. This is just some text. This is just some text. This is just some text. This is just some text. This is just some text.

\end{document}
```

The stamp is in the output pdf.  It is just no longer visible.  Is there an alternative, short of going the heavy-weight tikz route?

Comment: What about `\AddToShipoutPicture*` from the `eso-pic` package?

Comment: draftwartermark now use the new shipout hook, but with your redefinition you are destroying its code. Use the shipout/hooks directly, e.g. `\AddToHook{shipout/background}{\put(0pt,-\paperheight){\includegraphics{example-image.pdf}}}`  (adjust the values of the put command to place your graphic). Or use eso-pic (which uses the hooks too).

Comment: @ ulrike.  perfect answer.  can you please add it as a checkable answer, or should I based on your comment?